# Convert Unicode string to UTF-8, and then to JSON

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8, escaping

I want to encode a string in UTF-8 and view the corresponding UTF-8 bytes individually. In the Python REPL the following seems to work fine:

```
>>> unicode('©', 'utf-8').encode('utf-8')
'\xc2\xa9'
```

Note that I’m using [U+00A9 COPYRIGHT SIGN](http://codepoints.net/U+00A9) as an example here. The `'\xC2\xA9'` looks close to what I want — a string consisting of two separate code points: U+00C2 and U+00A9. (When UTF-8-decoded, it gives back the original string, `'\xA9'`.)

Then, I want the UTF-8-encoded string to be converted to a JSON-compatible string. However, the following doesn’t seem to do what I want:

```
>>> import json; json.dumps('\xc2\xa9')
'"\\u00a9"'
```

Note that it generates a string containing U+00A9 (the original symbol). Instead, I need the UTF-8-encoded string, which would look like `"\u00C2\u00A9"` in valid JSON.

TL;DR How can I turn `'©'` into `"\u00C2\u00A9"` in Python? I feel like I’m missing something obvious — is there no built-in way to do this?

Comment: **Note:** [The results of using `print` in the Python REPL depend on the `$LANG` environment variable.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3221297/96656) This introduces an extra layer of confusion when testing stuff like this.

Comment: That statement is wrong on many levels. UTF-8 is an encoding. Unicode is more like a database that maps numbers (code points) to symbols. Those numbers are then used by encodings such as UTF-8. It’s true that  unlike lots of other encodings, UTF-8 is able to encode/decode any Unicode symbol — but that doesn’t mean UTF-8 _is_ Unicode.

Comment: it means one thing -- converting "unicode" to "utf-8" has no meaning.

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky Sure it does.  Else, why would we need UTF-8 encoders/decoders?

Comment: You have them because internal string representation may be other than UTF-8. For example, UTF-16 on python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want `"\u00c2\u00a9"` as the output, give `json` a Unicode string as input.

```
>>> print json.dumps(u'\xc2\xa9')
"\u00c2\u00a9"
```

You can generate this Unicode string from the raw bytes:

```
s = unicode('©', 'utf-8').encode('utf-8')
s2 = u''.join(unichr(ord(c)) for c in s)
```

I think what you really want is `"\xc2\xa9"` as the output, but I'm not sure how to generate that yet.

Comment: I want to have `u'\u00A9'` as input (so, not like in your first example), and `'"\u00c2\u00a9"'` as output.

Comment: A shorter way to do it seems to be `json.dumps(unicodeString.encode('utf8').decode('latin1'))`.

Comment: @MathiasBynens, I think that the first 256 codepoints of Unicode correspond exactly to `latin1` so your short version would be correct. Very clever.

Comment: Yep — it was a suggestion by @nedbat, of [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) fame. It works correctly for all Unicode code points (just like your suggested solution). E.g. trying it with `unicodeString = u'\U0001D306'` gives `"\u00f0\u009d\u008c\u0086"`, which matches [the UTF-8 representation for U+1D306](http://codepoints.net/U+1D306).